# CloudFront FE throws CORS errors trying to connect to ECS with ALB for API server

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I have an API server up and running on ECS Fargate with Application Load Balancer managing network calls.  https://api.server.com
FE is deployed to an S3 bucket and managed by a Cloud Front. https://fe.server.com

They are both up and running but can't talk to each other. My FE was working fine talking to the old server (on pure EC2, no LoadBalancer).

> Access to fetch at 'https://api.server.com/apis/auth/login' from origin 'https://fe.server.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

How can I resolve this CORS problem?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the following to our fetch args

```
 fetchArgs.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
 fetchArgs.mode = 'no-cors';
 fetch(fullUrl, fetchArgs);
```